# Deny IronPython access to public functions not part of interface?

Tags: c#, interface, permissions, scope, ironpython

I've got an IronPython environment hosted in one of my applications. In that environment I'd like to access certain methods of an object that is represented by an interface. But I'd like to let IronPython only get access to those methods exported by the interface.

I can do this:

```
ITheInterface obj = (ITheInterface)origObj;
sc.SetVariable("obj", obj);
```

where sc is the scope, origObj is an instance of a class that implements ITheInterface and ITheInterface is... well... the interface.

But I still can access public methods of the origObj instance that are not *exported* by ITheInterface.

How can I restrict IronPython's access to only those methods that are exported by the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that IronPython makes all calls based on the runtime type of the object. To hide unwanted methods, create a class (TheInterfaceWrapper) that holds a ITheInterface reference but only implements the interface by forwarding to the proper method. That way, the runtime type doesn't have any extra methods.

The other option is intrusive on your other code, but you can add the [PythonHidden] attribute to methods you don't want to be visible from IronPython.

Comment: I'm thinking about a post-build step like PostSharp that injects the PythonHidden attribute into the IL to methods that are not exported by the interface. But that's a bit like breaking a butterfly on a wheel... I'd like to have an attribute that does the opposite of PythonHidden, like PythonVisible or something. But in the meantime I guess I'll give PythonHidden a try. Thanks.