# IronPython .NET class access via interface

Tags: c#, interface, ironpython

I am using IronPython to access a .net (C#) class instance from a running application, but I am trying to restrict access to only methods and properties in the class using an Interface.  This is not working as my Python can access ALL public methods and properies.

I have created a small test app to demo this problem and experiment with possible solutions, but so far it is having the same problem as my much larger production application.

My class instance is being shared with Python via a ScriptScope.SetVariable("TestApp", this) and this is working fine.

The relevant C# code follows:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace PythonTestObj
{
    public class PythonScriptRun
    {

        // Bunch of Python code here.  Not relevent

        public ITest GetProp()
        {
            ITest retVal = (ITest) _TestClass;
            return retVal;
        }

        public interface ITest
        {
            string HelloWorld { get; }
        }

        public class TestClass : ITest
        {
            public string HelloWorld
            {
                get
                {
                    return "Hello World";
                }
            }

            public string GoodbyeWorld
            {
                get
                {
                    return "Goodbye World";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following is my Python script in its entirety:

```
import System
import clr
import sys

clr.AddReference("PythonTestObj.dll")
from PythonTestObj import *

engOp = globals().get('TestApp')

#engOp now refers to an instance of TestClass through an ITest interface

# This print should work as HelloWorld is in the ITest
retStr = engOp.GetProp().HelloWorld
print retStr

# This should fail because GoodbuyWorld is not in ITest
retStr = engOp.GetProp().GoodbyeWorld
print retStr
```

When I run this python script I get the following output:

```
Hello World
Goodbye World
```

Since the GetProp() method returned an ITest interface, I am at a loss as to how it could find the GoodbyeWorld property!

Question: Is there a way to do this, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I found this question while trying to solve the same problem. Some additional searching turned up a question that is 5 years older and has a helpful answer:  [How to expose only the interface implementation of IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259809/how-to-expose-only-the-interface-implementation-to-ironpython), that might help you.

Comment: Here is another helpful question, [Deny IronPython access to public functions not part of interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166695/deny-ironpython-access-to-public-functions-not-part-of-interface)